# Run a program after ssh session terminates

Tags: ssh

I am trying to run a long java program on a server via ssh, I tried using:

```
command &
```

Which would work fine on my local machine, but when I terminate my local ssh connection, the program also terminates. Is there a way I can run this and have the output go to some text file so I can login and check completion at a later date?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

```
nohup command &
```